# How can i use update statements in c# correctly

Tags: c#, sql-update, oledb

This is my update statement that cosntains a syntax error, please can anyonje point out the error to me im having a real struggle, my knowlede isnt the best.

Updated but sti;ll having errors.

```
string sql = $"UPDATE Appointments SET AppDate = {dtpDate.Value.ToShortDateString()}, ContactName = {txtCustomer.Text}, ContactNumber = {txtNumber}, Comment = {txtComment} WHERE ID = {AppID}";
```

````
                String contactNo = txtNumber.Text.ToString();
                String comment = txtComment.Text.ToString();
                string date1 = dtpDate.Value.ToString("dd/M/yyyy");
                


                string sql = $"UPDATE Appointments SET AppDate = @Date1, ContactName = @Customer, ContactNumber = @ContactNo, Comment = @Comment WHERE ID = @AppID";

                SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
                param.ParameterName = "@Date1";
                param.Value = date1;
                param.ParameterName = "@Customer";
                param.Value = customer;
                param.ParameterName = "@ContactNo";
                param.Value = contactNo;
                param.ParameterName = "@Comment";
                param.Value = comment;
                param.ParameterName = "@AppID";
                param.Value = AppID;```
````

Comment: https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: You are not using parameterized query... Once you use that, you will not encounter the error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya please can you look at my update im still having errors

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: You are using the same parameter and setting it's name and value. Also not using the parameter anywhere in the code. I think you need to read more about using parameters in query from c#

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'"

Comment: You need to make a new parameter for every value. And of course, you need to add every single parameter to the parameters collection of the command.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asuming datatype of ContactName, ContactNumber and Comments as `VARCHAR`, dtpDate.Value as `Date` and ID to be of type `int`,
Your query needs to be have a syntax like this:

```
string sql = $"UPDATE Appointments SET AppDate = '{dtpDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}', ContactName = '{txtCustomer.Text}', ContactNumber = '{txtNumber}', Comment = '{txtComment}' WHERE ID = {AppID}";
```

During concatenation in C#, you need to make sure that string values are enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: Encouragement to not use parameterized queries is horrible advice.